# How to translate「暗戀」to English?

Tags: translation, traditional-characters

「暗戀」literally means "hidden relationship", but sometimes I found it also means "have a crush on someone".

I am wondering which one is the more common translation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

暗戀 is usually translated as having a crush, the chinese word usually means that the subject being crushed on does not know of it, while I feel the english word for crush can be interchanged with "like / have feelings for / fancy someone"

Comment: The phrase "secretly in love" is quite commonly used too.

Answer (score 0):

the individual meaning of the characters may not directly express the meaning of the word they combine to create, a crush can be considered a secret desire so I would imagine that crush is the correct translation.  my dictionary says anlian means 'to be secretly in love with'